# 404 when setting up Eclipse Dynamic Web Application

Tags: java, eclipse, http-status-code-404, tomcat7

This is the first time I have ever tried to set up a web application project on my own and for some reason I can't even get it to work with a hello world setup.  I have everything set to default, the JDK1.8 selected for compiling and an Tomcat7 server with a index.html page that has only text in it.  I should be able to right click on the projet and Run on Server after adding the project to the server but I keep getting a 404 even with this simple setup.  What am I missing?

[image: Setup]

Web.xml welcome list:

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
```

Comment: which URL are you accessing?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/[Project Name],  Eclipse hits it automatically when you run as.. run on server.

Comment: provide the details of project structure.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot access files under WEB-INF folder directly. Container will look for classes in WEB-INF/classes and jsp files under WEB-INF can be included by other JSP, but any browser requesting resources down there will get a 404 response.

You should change index.xhtml path from `webapp/WEB-INF/index.html` to `webapp/index.html` for corresponding to your web.xml